# Not getting the items in Carousel in Actions on Google

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

```
    app.intent('Our Events', (conv) =>{
  if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
    'phone surface in the simulator.');
  return;
}
  conv.ask(getdata());
  conv.ask('Events are here!');
});


function getdata()
{
  let carouselItems ={};
  var events = db.collection('events').get().then(snapshot =>{
                                                    snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
                                                      let itemdetails ={
                                                        title:doc.data().title,
                                                        description:doc.data().info,
image: new Image({
                                                                url:doc.data().image_url,
                                                                alt:'Image',
                                                            }),
                                                          };
                                                          carouselItems[doc.id]=itemdetails;
                                                          console.log(carouselItems[doc.id]);
                });
      });
      return new Carousel({
            title:'Our Events',
            items: carouselItems,
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Carousels are visual selection responses and they need to a unique key to be recognized. So you have to give selection key to all carousel item objects. In your case it seems you add objects without key to array.

Please check the sample below and try to create objects according to structure.

```
  items: {
    // Add the first item to the carousel
    'SELECTION_KEY_ONE': {
      synonyms: [
        'synonym 1',
        'synonym 2',
        'synonym 3',
      ],
      title: 'Title of First Carousel Item',
      description: 'This is a description of a carousel item.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'IMG_URL_AOG.com',
        alt: 'Image alternate text',
      }),
    },
    // Add the second item to the carousel
    'SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_HOME': {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Home Assistant',
        'Assistant on the Google Home',
    ],
      title: 'Google Home',
      description: 'Google Home is a voice-activated speaker powered by ' +
        'the Google Assistant.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'IMG_URL_GOOGLE_HOME.com',
        alt: 'Google Home',
      }),
    },
    // Add third item to the carousel
    'SELECTION_KEY_GOOGLE_PIXEL': {
      synonyms: [
        'Google Pixel XL',
        'Pixel',
        'Pixel XL',
      ],
      title: 'Google Pixel',
      description: 'Pixel. Phone by Google.',
      image: new Image({
        url: 'IMG_URL_GOOGLE_PIXEL.com',
        alt: 'Google Pixel',
      }),
    },
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to be rewritten so that your intent handler knows the operation is asynchronous. Note the addition of `async` and `await` keywords which will inform the interpreter when a given command is complete.

```
app.intent('Our Events', async (conv) =>{
  if (!conv.surface.capabilities.has('actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT')) {
  conv.ask('Sorry, try this on a screen device or select the ' +
    'phone surface in the simulator.');
  return;
}
  conv.ask(await getdata());
  conv.ask('Events are here!');
});


async function getdata() {
  let carouselItems ={};
  const snapshot = db.collection('events').get()
  snapshot.forEach(doc=>{
    let itemdetails ={
      title:doc.data().title,
      description:doc.data().info,
      image: new Image({
        url:doc.data().image_url,
        alt:'Image',
      }),
    };
   carouselItems[doc.id]=itemdetails;
   console.log(carouselItems[doc.id]);
  });

  return new Carousel({
    title:'Our Events',
    items: carouselItems,
  });
}
```

Comment: The above solution is not working. Getting errors as conv not defined, async and await too not defined.

Comment: Which version of Node are you using?

Comment: I am using dialogflow with following dependencies:                                                                      "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using? If you're using Node 6 instead of Node 8, you may need to rewrite the async code to use Promises as the syntax.